# Error building Player: Win32Exception

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

> Error building Player: Win32Exception: ApplicationName='C:/Users/CASA/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk/platforms/android-23\aapt.exe', CommandLine='package -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/Users/CASA/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk/platforms/android-23\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_', CurrentDirectory='Temp/StagingArea'

I am having a error when I am building an android version of my game, I have already tried these solution but did not work

- copying/cutting zipalign.exe from build-tools to tools.
- Deleting and reinstalling my SDK

Answer (score 0):

You installed **Android SDK** but you did not install JDK(**Java Development Kit**). You can get it here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Under **Java SE Development Kit 8u77**, there are Windows x86(32 bit) and Windows x64(64 bit) versions listed. Make sure to download the one that matches your OS.

Comment: i have already installed,but there is still the same error :c

Comment: @Alexis. Restart computer after installing

Comment: @Alexis You didn't have to open a new error. I think both errors are related. I have few questions for you. What Unity version are you using? What version of Android OS are you running?  In Unity, Go to File->Build Settings->Player Settings->Minimum API. What is your Minimum API set to? and finally what version of SDK do you have?

Comment: Ok, i am using unity 3.5, the minimum api is level 14, mi  Java SE Development Kit is  8u77,  i don't know how to check what version of unity i am using  but i think is  the version  4.0

Comment: You check the version of unity by going to **Help** -> **About Unity** in the Editor. The version is printed on the left.

Comment: I don't think that profanity is allowed on this site. You can check the Android version in Settings->System Settings and info or something similar. Just look in the settings and you'll find it. Which JDK did you download? 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: I did not say in that way, anyway,  my android version is 4.0 and my JDK is 32 bit

Comment: Ok. That's all I need. You said you are using unity 3.5.... That is so old. You have to update to 5. Any reason you can't update to 5?

Comment: No special reason man, so i am going to install version 5.0 and i'll try again; so if you dont mind how can i reconect with you in case that another error appears?

Comment: I am here. Just comment here if it is not working. Get 5.4 here http://unity3d.com/unity/beta